# Splitting strings inside a list of lists by spaces

Tags: python, string, list

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
t = [['I will','take','care'],['I know','what','to','do']]
```

As you see in the first list I have `'I will'` and I want them to split into two elements `'I'` and `'will'`, s.t the result is:

```
[['I', 'will', 'take', 'care'], ['I', 'know', 'what', 'to', 'do']]
```

Quick and dirty algorithm is the following:

```
train_text_new = []


for sent in t:
  new = []
  for word in sent:
    temp = word.split(' ')
    for item2 in temp:
      new.append(item2)


  train_text_new.append(new)
```

But I would like to know if there is a more readable and maybe more efficient algorithm for solving this problem.

Comment: Will it be always the 1st element of sublist that you want to split?

Comment: Can there be more than 1 space in a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a simple generator that yields the splits, then use that in a list comprehension:

```
t = [['I will','take','care'],['I know','what','to','do']]

def splitWords(l):
    for words in l:
        yield from words.split()

[list(splitWords(sublist)) for sublist in t]
# [['I', 'will', 'take', 'care'], ['I', 'know', 'what', 'you', 'to', 'do']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.
Assuming splitting always happens to the first element of the sublist

```
t = [['I will','take','care'],['I know','what','to','do']]
[start.split()+rest for start,*rest in t]
# [['I', 'will', 'take', 'care'], ['I', 'know', 'what', 'to', 'do']]
```

If splitting should happen to any word in sublist try this.

```
[[j for i in lst for j in i.split()]for lst in t]
# [['I', 'will', 'take', 'care'], ['I', 'know', 'what', 'to', 'do']]
```

Answer (score 2):

joining every inner list to a string usin `join` and splitting that string using `split` to list will do the trick

```
t = [['I will','take','care'],['I know','what','to','do']]
res = [' '.join(i).split() for i in t]
print(res)
# output [['I', 'will', 'take', 'care'], ['I', 'know', 'what', 'to', 'do']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to do the flattening after splitting:

```
from itertools import chain

t = [['I will','take','care'],['I know','what','to','do']]

print([list(chain.from_iterable(x.split() for x in y)) for y in t])
```

Output:

```
[['I', 'will', 'take', 'care'], ['I', 'know', 'what', 'to', 'do']]
```